# Is there a replacement for `net.sf.ehcache.Statistics`?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Is there a replacement for `net.sf.ehcache.Statistics`?  Something along the lines of `org.ehcache.Statistics`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact replacement, but in `org.ehcache.core.statistics` is an interface `CacheStatistics` which is implemented by i.e. `DefaultCacheStatistics` which covers some of the methods such as `getCacheHits` and `getCacheMisses`.

The corresponding [Github issue](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/1940) points to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303449/3603660) stating that an official API is available via [`DefaultStatisticsService`](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/ehcache/core/statistics/DefaultStatisticsService.java) but not yet documented.

Comment: The answer linked above points to this [unit test](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/master/integration-test/src/test/java/org/ehcache/integration/statistics/CacheCalculationTest.java).